# how do I babel transpile es6 code in gulp-jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, gulp, babeljs

I want to transpile es6 code  to es5 and run jasmine tests on it and later get code coverage for es6 code.I have done it in mocha and now trying switch over to jasmine.

```
gulp.src(["./test/loginTest.js"], { read: false })
    .pipe(mocha({
      reporter: "spec",
      require: [__dirname + "/test/utils/dom.js"],
      compilers: ["js:babel-core/register"]
    }))
```